# Using docker image ubuntu:latest not copying file to desired directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu, devops

I am using docker image ubuntu:latest pipeline run successfully without any error but docker not copy file to desired directory instead copying it on docker volume here is my pipeline

```
image: ubuntu:latest

stages:
  - deploy

deploy_to_apache:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install -y git apache2
    - rm -rf /var/www/html/*   # Clear Apache directory
    - mkdir -p /root/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_Key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    - git clone git@gitlab.com:User_name/project_name.git /tmp/project
    - cp -r /tmp/project/* /var/www/html/
    - service apache2 restart
  only:
    - main  # Deploy only when changes are pushed to the main branch
  tags:
    - CommonRunner
```

I try to use absolute path.
cd to path while running pipeline

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a plain `ubuntu` container and manage it the way you would a traditional VM.  A more typical Docker approach would be to write a Dockerfile, maybe starting `FROM httpd` to use the Apache HTTP server, and `COPY` the files into it.  You should not need `git` inside the container, and commands like `service` don't usually work and aren't necessary.  Docker's [Containerize an application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial is Node-focused, but runs through the basic sequence.

Comment: Hi David thanks but I am unable to understand what you just said is there any way I can make this pipeline works?